# Setting "REAL" work/scratch workspace in ESRI/ERDAS etc

Tags: arcmap, geoprocessing, installation, erdas-imagine

I thought the issue was only in ARCGIS but it seems that ERDAS does the same thing. I have my C with 1.7TB and my D with 10TB and my scratch set to d:\scratch but still ERDAS (and ESRI) fills my profile with it's temp data...why? see the image below (in this example I have tried to set the temp space to c:\scratch)

In ARCGIS
 I have tried C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Utilities\AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe--> run as admin-->System Paths-->last option "Output Temp file path" and set to D:\scratch.

I have tried "solutions" from http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/3300-ArcGIS-10-Default-Geodatabase

**How can we resolve this?**[image]

Comment: It worked for me by just editing the scratch workspace under geoprocessing in arcmap.  Once I did this, and pointed it to a live gdb for my scratch, it worked

Comment: Great. Have you tried to process a file that has an uncompressed size larger than your c: drive? to check monitor your c:\users\...\AppData\Local\Temp directory while running a process. If this grows then the issue persists...

Comment: I don't get this issue George.  At my clients, the C: drive is heavily tied down, and so I access all of my data from the D: drive, where my scratch area is set up.  However, I do clear down my 'in_memory' area after every loop, I also compact the gdb.  One thing that does happen to the scratch db, is that it continues to grow, even if you remove in_memory data, so it's possibly this causing your issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the Windows `%TEMP%` variable to a different drive so all temp not just ESRI stuff is redirected.

<kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>pause</kbd> *>> Advanced >> Environment Variables*.

From there slap [New] to override the user profile temp or [Edit] to change the system wide temp.

[image: windows dialog for setting environment variables]

I don't know if this is still true, but I've encountered some geoprocessing tools which would write to the ESRI installation directory(!) in some circumstances (`c:\program files\arcgis\bin`). Just something to keep an eye on.

Comment: Thanks. Trying this as well. Will test with a large process and see.

Comment: Note that this global change will affect *all* applications that use this standard location.

Comment: @jpmc26, yes. that's noted in first sentence (but perhaps not clear enough? I'll adjust)

Comment: Apologies. I must have missed it. Maybe just make it more prominent for people who aren't paying as much attention like me?